# Java NullPointerException and ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Given the following:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IntegerList {

    public ArrayList<Integer> list;
    private int front;
    private int[] integers = getIntegers();

    public IntegerList (int maxCapacity) {
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(maxCapacity);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxCapacity; i++) {
            list.add(null);
        }
        front = 0;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        if (list.get(front) == null) 
            return 0;
        else 
            return 10;
    }

    public int[] getIntegers() {
        int[] integers = new int[getCapacity()];
        return integers;
    }
}
```

When I instantiate the class IntegerList by passing 20 to the maxCapacity parameter in the constructor I get the following message at compile time:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at IntegerList.getCapacity(IntegerList.java:18)
    at IntegerList.getIntegers(IntegerList.java:26)
    at IntegerList.<init>(IntegerList.java:7)
    at Test.main(Test.java:5)
```

Why do I get the exception? It appears that the problem is in list.get(front) in getCapacity(), but does this not return null, thus returning true for the if statement?

Comment: @AniketThakur Not in a `List`, they won't.

Comment: Yeah confused it for an `array`.

Comment: Thanks all for your input - much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initializer `integers = getIntegers();` is implicitly inserted at the top of your constructor and runs before `list = new ArrayList<Integer>(maxCapacity);`.

Using anything other than an immediately evaluable expression in an initializer is frequently asking for trouble of this sort. It's better to do complex initialization like that in the constructor explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the statement:
 `private int[] integers = getIntegers();`

When you instantiate this class it leads to invocation of method `getIntegers` which invokes `getCapacity` but `list` is not yet initialized and it is `null`. So when it invokes  `list.get(front)` it gets `NPE`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `private int[] integers = getIntegers();` gets executed during initialization of `IntegerList` instance.

Change your code to

```
public int getCapacity() {
    if (list == null || list.get(front) == null) 
        return 0;
    else 
        return 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove that null thing in the constructor array. By default Nulls are already there. 
Secondly change **private int[] integers = getIntegers();**
thing to **private int[] integers;**

and do this as the last line of constructor code:

**integers = getIntegers();**

Answer (score 0):

The point is the `instance member initialization takes place secretly before the explicit constructor code` you provide hence in your case

```
private int[] integers = getIntegers();
```

**kicks in as the first line of execution** when you call the constructor by initializing the IntegerClass and at that point the ArrayList list is still pointing to null and hence can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

look into this,

```
public int getCapacity() {
        if (list.get(front) == null) 
            return 0;
        else 
            return 10;
    }
```

you are getting nullPointerException because you are storing `null`. and `list.get(front)` when you try to get value it'll throw exception before comparison.

its batter you store 0 instead of null. or wtite this code within try catch block. like following.

```
 public int getCapacity() {
  int result =0;
try{
      if (list.get(front) != null) 
             return 10;
   }catch(Exception e) {
     return 0
 }

}
```